# React Js: <Link/> not working after build in gh-pages or netlify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deployment, github-pages, netlify

I've built a react front end for my rest api. I've got them both deployed! However my navbar component has  tags and do not work after clicking on them once. This happens in both netlify and gh-pages. Has anyone encountered this solution before? I am using HashRouter instead of ReactRouter.  Thanks for taking your time with this :)

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default ({ context }) => {
  const authedUser = context.authenticatedUser;

  //Nav bar conditionally rendered on if the user is logged in or not

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="header-div">
        <div>
          <Link to="/" className="header-div-left">
            
            Student Courses
          </Link>
        </div>

        <nav>
          {authedUser ? (
            <React.Fragment>
              <div className="header-div-right">
                <span className="header-div-right">
                  
                  Welcome {authedUser.firstName} {authedUser.lastName}
                </span>
                <Link className="header-div-right" to="/signout">
                  
                  Sign Out
                </Link>
              </div>
            </React.Fragment>
          ) : (
            <React.Fragment>
              <div className="header-div-right-up-in">
                <Link className="header-div-right" to="/signup">
                  Sign Up
                </Link>
                <Link className="header-div-right" to="/signin">
                  Sign In
                </Link>
              </div>
            </React.Fragment>
          )}
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  HashRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Switch
} from 'react-router-dom';


import './App.css';
import CourseDetail from './components/CourseDetail';
import Courses from './components/Courses';
import CreateCourse from './components/CreateCourse';
import Header from './components/Header';
import UpdateCourse from './components/UpdateCourse';
import UserSignIn from './components/UserSignIn';
import UserSignOut from './components/UserSignOut';
import UserSignUp from './components/UserSignUp';
import NotFound from './components/NotFound';
import PrivateRoute from './PrivateRoute';
import withContext from './Context';

//Connecting the SignUp & SignIn to context.

//This shares the data and actions throughout the component tree

/* Adding the const's as the component to the route handler
lets the components UserSignIn & UserSignUp gain access to 
the function in context and any data or actions passed into
<Context.Provider value={value}> */

const UserSignInWithContext = withContext(UserSignIn);
const UserSignUpWithContext = withContext(UserSignUp);
const UserSignOutWithContext = withContext(UserSignOut);

/* To let the user know they are signed in
need to make changes to the name display in the end header */

const HeaderWithContext = withContext(Header);
const CoursesWithContext = withContext(Courses);
const CourseDetailsWithContext = withContext(CourseDetail);
const UpdateCourseWithContext = withContext(UpdateCourse)
const CreateCourseWithContext = withContext(CreateCourse)

export default () => (
  <Router>
    <div >
    <HeaderWithContext/>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={CoursesWithContext} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/courses/create" component={CreateCourseWithContext} />
        <Route exact path="/courses/:id" component={CourseDetailsWithContext} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/courses/:id/update" component={UpdateCourseWithContext} />
        <Route path="/signin" component={UserSignInWithContext} />
        <Route path="/signup" component={UserSignUpWithContext} />
        <Route path="/signout" component={UserSignOutWithContext} />
        <Route component={NotFound} />
      </Switch >
    </div >
  </Router>
  
);
```

Comment: Did you deploy the build bundle after running `npm run build`?  There is a good doc on how to deploy here: https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages

and here: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#github-pages-https-pagesgithubcom

Comment: Hello Glen, cheers I will have a look now :)